# What is the correct way to use MPI with thread

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, boost-thread

I have a piece of code like this, running on 4 MPI process.

```
for (i=0;i<niter;i++){
    //.. do something with temprs

    memcpy(rs, temprs,..) // copy temprs content to rs     
    MPI_Gather(rs,...0...); //gather result to 0
    if (mpiRank == 0) writeToDisk(rs);
}
```

I want to put 2 last line of code into a function **comm_and_save** then threaded it so that It can run in parallel with the remaining code, something like below:

```
boost::thread t1;

for (i=0;i<niter;i++){
    //.. do something with temprs

    t1.join(); // make sure previous comm_and_save done
    memcpy(rs, temprs,..) // copy temprs content to rs 
    t1 = boost::thread( comm_and_save, rs );
}
```

However, the code sometime run, sometime hang, sometime throws some error:

```
local QP operation err (QPN 5a0407, WQE @ 00000f02, CQN 280084, index 100677)
  [ 0] 005a0407
  [ 4] 00000000
  [ 8] 00000000
  [ c] 00000000
  [10] 0270c84f
  [14] 00000000
  [18] 00000f02
  [1c] ff100000
```

Please enlighten me which part I'm doing incorrectly
Thank you

Comment: you have to join threads.  at least... what is rs?  comm_and_save? is it function?

Comment: @Anycorn: as I said "I put 2 last line of code into a function comm_and_save" .. so It just wrap MPI_Gather and writeToDisk. and I did join thread "t1.join()". rs is just ... result need to be gather to node 0

Comment: comm_and_save(rs) will call function outside the thread and then pass the return value to thread.

Comment: @Anycorn: I don't get your point... I'm asking here why it doesn't work correctly

Comment: and you do call `MPI_Init_thread`?

Comment: you probably meant `boost::thread(comm_and_save, rs)`?

Comment: @Anycorn: yes that's a typo thanks for pointing it out, I definitely put MPI_Init, because It's working correctly in the first version

Comment: boost thread args are passed by *value*, not reference.  what is rs?

Comment: rs is an array, is value and ref matter here ? anyway, I notice MPI_INIT_THREAD is not MPI_INIT, I will try that

Comment: i couldnt be 100% sure due to overloading what rs is.  Be sure to check returbn value of MPI_Init_thread:  Available level of thread suppor

Comment: Thanks @Anycorn I think MPI_INIT_THREAD is the cause, do you want to make it an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MPI_Init_thread`:
http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-20-html/node165.htm

and check return status:  Available level of thread support

Cheerz.